# getting wrong rendering in Image over image using HTML

Tags: marketing-cloud, content

I am trying to add one image over another image, however i am unable to do so , while previewing and testing, it's rendering correctly however in outlook it's getting misplaced

Please can someone help me.

.fishes
    {
      position: relative;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
 
    
     .fish1
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 40%;
      left: 12%;
    }
    
       .fish2
    {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5%;
      left: 12%;
    }
    
     .fish3
    {
      position: absolute;
      top: 41%;
      right: 13%;
    }
    
      .fish4
    {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 5%;
      right: 13%;
    }
 .

```
<img src="IMG1.jpg" class="fishes" style="display: block; margin: 0px; outline: none; padding: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: center; height: auto;"
title="test" width="600">


<img src="IMG2.png" class="fish1" style="display: block; margin: 0px; outline: none; padding: 0px;  height: auto;" title="Learn_more1" width="48">

 <img src="IMG2.png" class="fish2" style="display: block; margin: 0px; outline: none; padding: 0px;  height: auto;" title="Learn_more2" width="48">
 
 <img src="IMG2.png" class="fish3" style="display: block; margin: 0px; outline: none; padding: 0px;  height: auto;" title="Learn_more3" width="48">
 
  <img src="IMG2.png" class="fish4" style="display: block; margin: 0px; outline: none; padding: 0px;  height: auto;" title="Learn_more4" width="48">
```

Comment: You should check on HTML-focused support resources.

Comment: I have to do this.......It's rendering correctly in browser and in preview and test and not in outlook

Comment: Your issue is not related to Salesforce

Answer (score 1):

Firstly please be informed that the technique of coding HTML Emails is different. In order to support multiple MSPs [Mail Box Providers] you may have to use the Old School method of coding; specifically with the TABLE concept rather than using DIV or P tags.

To answer your above query, Outlook does NOT support many features.
So suggest you use this valuable resource to check why specific CSS property is NOT working.

CSS Support guide = https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/

here in your case the property `position:xxx` is NOT supported.
[image]